# Why am I getting Undefined property: stdClass:: with php 8 nullsafe operator

Tags: php, null, null-coalescing-operator, nullsafe

Php 8.0 introduced the nullsafe operator which can be used like so `$foo?->bar?->baz;`.
I have a code sample running on php 8.1 that throws the error `Undefined property: stdClass::$first_name` even though it is using the nullsafe operator:

```php
$reference = (object) $reference; // Cast of array to object

return [
    'FirstName' => $reference?->first_name,
];
```

To solve the error, I have to use the null coalescing operator:

```php
$reference = (object) $reference; // Cast of array to object

return [
    'FirstName' => $reference->first_name ?? null,
];
```

Why is the nullsafe operator throwing an error in this case?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You seem to have a slight misunderstanding of what the nullsafe operator does.

If `$reference` was `null`, then `$reference?->first_name` would return `null` with no warning, but since `$reference` is actually an object, `?->` just functions like a normal object operator, hence the undefined property warning.

Comment: So how are you supposed to do it when you have a reference chain where the first object definitely exists? e.g. $exists->maybe->also_maybe ?

Comment: Basically, this operator only comes into play if the the left-hand side is `null`. If the `$exists` object is set, but has no `maybe` property, then `$exists->maybe`, will produce the same issue the question is asking about where the nullsafe operator isn't really useful. If the `maybe` property _is_ present, but might have a null value, then the nullsafe operator could be used after it to prevent a warning when trying to read `also_maybe`, or anything else chained after that. If you don't know whether the first property in the chain exists or not, it's probably better to use `??` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a try-catch in case you have many nested properties:

```
try {
    if ($response->foo->bar->foo->bar->status == 'something') {
        ...
    }
} catch (\ErrorException $ex) {
    // Property missing exception will be caught here
}
```